# "ImagePullBackOff" error while trying to deploy a Dockerimage to Kubernetes on a remote server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, docker-image

I am working on a remote server and I had created a Docker image called as "triton_server_image" on the server and wanted to run the tritonon my remote server. It was successfull and it was running. But then I had to deploy the docker image to Kubernetes. For that, I wrote a deployment.yaml file and a service.yaml file and then ran the command - `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` but then I got this error -
`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  9s    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/triton-inference-server-5cd479476d-g98rl to ttogpu
  Normal   Pulling    8s    kubelet            Pulling image "triton_server_image:latest"
  Warning  Failed     7s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "triton_server_image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/triton_server_image:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/triton_server_image:latest": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
  Warning  Failed     7s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    6s    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "triton_server_image:latest"
  Warning  Failed     6s    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff`
```

But since I am working on the remote server I can see that the image name is correct and there are no isses with that. I ran `docker images` to recheck and the image name was correct. so, why is it that I am getting the error? And I don't have the docker credentials , it just that I am working on the remote server so we created the docker image locally on the server because docker was previously installed.

I took some reference frm this - [Deployments](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), but it did not work out

Comment: You need to push your image to a registry, and include the complete `registry.example.com/triton_server_image:tag` name in your Kubernetes `image:` tag.  Do not try to directly push images to the nodes.  Make sure to use a unique tag per build and not `...:latest` or another fixed string.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `ImagePullPolicy: Never` to use local Docker image.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: triton_server
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: triton_server_image:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
...
```

Default value of `ImagePullPolicy` is `Always` if you use `latest` tag for image. It means, Kubernetes always tries to pull the given image `triton_server:latest` from `docker.io`.

**EDIT**

If your server Kubernetes cluster installed and the server which has the docker image are different, you should push the docker image to any registry. If avaiable, you can use the public registry `docker.io` like below.

```
docker build -t docker.io/(your docker.io ID)/triton_server_image:latest Dockerfile
docker push docker.io/(your docker.io ID)/triton_server_image:latest
```

Then edit your `deployment.yaml`. `imagePullPolicy` can be either `IfNotPresent` or `Always`.

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: docker.io/(your docker.io ID)/triton_server_image:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
...
```

Comment: I tried setting the imagePullPolicy to Never but it showed this error:
  Warning  ErrImageNeverPull  5s (x8 over 72s)  kubelet            Container image "triton_server_image:latest" is not present with pull policy of Never
  Warning  Failed             5s (x8 over 72s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImageNeverPull

Comment: Your error message says that there is no such docker image in your Kubernetes server. Are the server Kubernetes cluster installed and the server which has the docker image same? If not, you should push your docker image to any registry like `docker.io`.